# Panels page - node template - comments won't appear

Tags: panels, comments

I'm using Drupal 7. I've got a Panel page set up that comprises a content type, followed by up to two page views based on taxonomy terms. The content type is set to allow comments, and when I use it alone (ie. not as part of the node template) the comments works fine. But when I have it as part of the panel page, no comments appear.

Can anyone think of what I'm doing wrong? I've asked this question on the Drupal forums but haven't received an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you are seeing the teaser view which may remove the comments, otherwise check to see if the panel settings allows the the comments to be shown